# Rails device and redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, device

Im use device for sign_in\up

and have `before_action :authenticate_user!`

My problem is when user not logged in and i click to sign in
it calls form for sign_in and after fill it redirect me on the same page

For example- i'm not logged in and i'm on root page and want to see `products/1` i clicking to `show` modal pops up i enter my credentials and it redirects me to the same page

But after sign in i want to be at `products/1`

session controller

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :js
  layout false
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate(auth_options)

    if resource && resource.active_for_authentication?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    end
  end

end
```

template  create.js.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in?%>
<%= request.referrer%>
  window.location.href='<%= request.referrer %>'
<% else %>
  $('#login_popup input').parent().addClass('inputbox_error');
  $('#log_error_messages').show();
  $('input').keydown(function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass('inputbox_error')
    $('#log_error_messages').hide();
  })
<% end %>
```

what should i change after `<% if user_signed_in?%>`?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to redirect user after sign in you can use after_sign_in_path_for method in Devise::SessionsController

First store the url you were on in `session` upon showing login modal like :

```
session[:login_redirect] = url
```

Then after sign in redirect user to that url.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     session[:login_redirect]
  end
end
```

Also update your routes.rb with session routes :

```
devise_for :user, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions"}
```